# PHP Warning: Warning: array_shift() expects parameter 1 to be array

Tags: php, wordpress

```
Warning: array_shift() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given in /hermes/walnaweb01a/b1374/moo.peachdesigninccom/tools4hardwood/wp-content/themes/listings/homepage_loops/content-listingsum.php on line 18
```

Is an error I'm getting on this page http://www.tools4hardwoods.com/home-2/ and I'm having no luck. Can some one help me debug?

Heres the full code:

```
<div class="car-list">
    <div class="car-img">
        <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()): ?>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail("home_listing"); ?></a>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="car-info">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3></a>
        <h2 class="car-price"><?php get_listing_price(); ?></h2>
        <ul class="car-tags clear">
            <?php
            global $post;
            $configuration = get_listing_display_attributes($post->ID);
            if ($configuration):
                foreach ($configuration as $tax) {
                    $terms = get_the_terms($post->ID,$tax);
                    if ($terms):
                        $term = array_shift($terms);
                        $term_link = get_term_link($term->slug,$term->taxonomy);
                        $term_name = $term->name;
                        $taxonomy = get_taxonomy($term->taxonomy);
                        ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo $term_link; ?>"><?php echo $term_name; ?></a>
                    <?php
                    endif;
                }
            endif;
            ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you get if you `print_r($terms)`? It's not an array here. WP says it can return false.

Comment: $79 for a dewalt hand sander?

Comment: Could you put your suggestion inside of the full code or at least let me know which line of code to replace it with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @Jeremy, this part of your code may return `WP_Error` instance:

```
// May return array, false or WP_Error object.
$terms = get_the_terms($post->ID,$tax);
```

So you have to update your conditional, make sure that the `$terms` is an array and not `WP_Error` object.

```
<?php

global $post;
$configuration = get_listing_display_attributes($post->ID);
if ($configuration):
    foreach ($configuration as $tax) {
        $terms = get_the_terms($post->ID,$tax);
        // Update your conditional here.
        if (is_array($terms) && ! is_wp_error($terms)):
            $term = array_shift($terms);
            $term_link = get_term_link($term->slug,$term->taxonomy);
            $term_name = $term->name;
            $taxonomy = get_taxonomy($term->taxonomy); ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $term_link; ?>"><?php echo $term_name; ?></a>
        <?php endif;
    }
endif;
?>
```

The [`is_wp_error()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_wp_error) is a built-in Wordpress method to check whether the passed parameter is an instance of `WP_Error` class.

Hope this help!

Answer (score 1):

The [get_the_terms()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/) function can return more than just an array or false. It can also return a [WP_Error](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_error/) object.

By doing `if ($terms)` you are only checking for it to be truthy, which an object *is*.

Instead you should do this:

```
if (is_array($terms)) {
   // Do something
} elseif ($terms instanceof WP_Error) {
   // Handle error
}
```

Comment: Could you put your suggestion inside of the full code or at least let me know which line of code to replace it with?